# Reading Exchange active directory info

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server

No matter the research that I do, I can't find anywhere the information to get access to the Exchange information on the active directory.

I am using `userprincipal` and `accountmanagement` already to access the AD user's info. Is there a similar way for Exchange?

I just want to read the following:

- ActiveSync enabled
- Mailbox Size Quota
- The proxies

These information are all available in the "user and computer Active Directory" that we have access to. I just need to figure out how to access them. Is there a class for that already?

regards,

Comment: Try to find what you are looking for in ADSI Edit, the proxies are in proxyAddresses. Then you can pull those fields from your program.

Answer (score 0):

> > ActiveSync enabled

Use the ProtocolSetting Attribute

> > Mailbox Size Quota

This would only be set if the user has a specific Mailbox Quota value set by default this would be null and the Mailbox Database setting would be used see http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/09/20/3394913.aspx. The Ad attributes for this are mDBStorageQuota,mDBOverQuotaLimit,mDBOverHardQuotaLimit,mDBUseDefaults

> > The Proxies

Use the proxyAddresses attribute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679424(v=vs.85).aspx